# PHP function store elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using a front end Javascript text editor, that submits data in html format, also convert all images to base64 encoded format.

The following function will parse $_POST super global, for html content and store encoded images in images folder along with their appropriate extension.

```
$html = preg_replace_callback("/src=\"data:([^\"]+)\"/", function ($matches) {
    list($contentType, $encContent) = explode(';', $matches[1]);
    if (substr($encContent, 0, 6) != 'base64') {
        return $matches[0];
    }
    $imgBase64 = substr($encContent, 6);
    $imgFilename = md5($imgBase64); // Get unique filename
    $imgExt = '';
    switch($contentType) {
        case 'image/jpeg':  $imgExt = 'jpg'; break;
        case 'image/gif':   $imgExt = 'gif'; break;
        case 'image/png':   $imgExt = 'png'; break;
        default:            return $matches[0]; 
    }

   // Here is where I'm able to echo image names with thier extentions.
   echo $imgFilename . '.' . $imgExt;

    $imgPath = 'zendesk-images/'.$imgFilename.'.'.$imgExt;
    // Save the file to disk if it doesn't exist
    if (!file_exists($imgPath)) {
        $imgDecoded = base64_decode($imgBase64);
        $fp = fopen($imgPath, 'w');
        if (!$fp) {
            return $matches[0];
        }
        fwrite($fp, $imgDecoded);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    return 'src="'.$imgPath.'"';
}, $html);
```

I'm able to echo image names in the following line

```
echo $imgFilename . '.' . $imgExt;
```

I'm trying to store converted images file names in an array, but I haven't been successful in doing that.

Here is what I have tried, initialize an array before the function

```
$Images = array();
```

then instead of echoing, I have tried to do the following.

```
$Images[] = $imgFilename . '.' . $imgExt;
```

But that didn't work, and I end up with empty array

Comment: php variables are case sensitive. `$Images` and `$images` are two totally different variables.

Comment: Becareful, if u try $images[] = $imgFilename . '.' . $imgExt; , then you must have $images = array(); and not $Images = array();

Comment: And i do believe that if you declare $images = array() before the call to preg_replace_callback() then $images[] = ... is out of this scope and won't be able to access $images

Comment: ...function($matches) using (&$images) {..

Comment: @JurgisGregov Damn didn't know it works for internal functions :) You should post this as an answer so that the OP will be able to set this as the MVA

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use $images in outer scope you need something like

```
$images = array();
$html = preg_replace_callback("/src=\"data:([^\"]+)\"/", function ($matches) use(&$images) {
    //...
    $images[] = $imgFilename . '.' . $imgExt;
    //...
}
echo implode(', ', $images);
```